# gdkmm: how to destroy gdk window?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gdk

**Status quo:**
I have a custom widget (MyWidget) with an event window.
**Problem:** if I create, show and then, later, hide and destroy the widget I get the following message from the application:

`Gdk-WARNING **: losing last reference to undestroyed window`

**What I've found out:** I've had a look in `gdkwindow.c` file and this message is reported when `GDK_WINDOW_DESTROYED(window) == FALSE`. So the thing I do not understand is how I should destroy my window correctly so that eventually `gdk_window_destroy()` function is called. I thought that the best place to call it was the `Gdk::~Window()` destructor. But it's empty. And moreover `gdk_window_destroy()` is absent in `gdkwindow.cc` file at all.

The `on_realize()` and `on_unrealize()` call-backs are below.

```
class MyWidget : public Gtk::Widget
{
...
private:
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Window>   _event_window;
...
};

void Gtk::MyWidget::on_realize()
{
    GdkWindowAttr       attributes;
    const Allocation    & allocation = get_allocation();

    attributes.event_mask = GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK;

    attributes.x = allocation.get_x();
    attributes.y = allocation.get_y();
    attributes.width = allocation.get_width();
    attributes.height = allocation.get_height();
    attributes.wclass = GDK_INPUT_ONLY;
    attributes.window_type = GDK_WINDOW_CHILD;

    _event_window = Gdk::Window::create(get_parent_window(), &attributes, GDK_WA_X | GDK_WA_Y);
    _event_window->set_user_data(Widget::gobj());

    set_window(get_parent_window());

    set_realized();
}

void Gtk::MyWidget::on_unrealize()
{
    _event_window->set_user_data(NULL);
    _event_window.reset();

    set_realized(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turned out that the correctest way to destroy the GDK window you have created with `Gdk::Window::create()` is.. guess what? to call `Gtk::Widget::unrealize()` in `on_unrealize()` method of your custom widget because apart from other things this base method calls `gdk_window_destroy()` for the widget's GDK window. And for that your widget **has** to be "windowful" (i.e you should call `set_has_window(true);` in the constructor and `set_window(<your allocated GDK window>);` in `on_realize()` callback.  Very obvious approach, isn't it?

I should also say something about `Gtk::Widget::realize()`. Unlike `Gtk::Widget::unrealize()` you should call `Gtk::Widget::realize()` *only* if your widget *doesn't have* a GDK window (the method assumes that as an assertion).

Unfortunately I didn't have time and wish to get to the very bottom of it and endevour to understand why it has been done so and what reasons and consequences this approach has. Otherwise I would provide more detailed explanation.

You can find an official example from GTK's tutorial on custom widgets
[here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-custom-widgets.html.en).

Also the code of my widget now looks like that:

```
class MyWidget : public Gtk::Widget
{
...
private:
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Window>   _event_window;
...
};

void Gtk::MyWidget::on_realize()
{
    GdkWindowAttr       attributes;
    const Allocation    & allocation = get_allocation();

    attributes.event_mask = GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | GDK_EXPOSURE;

    attributes.x = allocation.get_x();
    attributes.y = allocation.get_y();
    attributes.width = allocation.get_width();
    attributes.height = allocation.get_height();
    attributes.wclass = GDK_INPUT_OUTPUT;
    attributes.window_type = GDK_WINDOW_CHILD;

    _event_window = Gdk::Window::create(get_parent_window(), &attributes, GDK_WA_X | GDK_WA_Y);
    _event_window->set_user_data(Widget::gobj());

    set_window(_event_window);

    set_realized();
}

void Gtk::MyWidget::on_unrealize()
{
    _event_window->set_user_data(NULL);
    _event_window.reset();

    Widget::unrealize();
    // it will call gdk_destroy_window() and
    // set_realized(false);
}
```